# mod-rewrite issue with spaces in the url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /categories.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is my RewriteRule, it deals with categories such as /categories/Family perfectly that URL displays the page as I would like it too, However with something such as /categories/Web%20Design I get an The requested URL /categories/Web Design was not found on this server.

This is a pain, I've even tried to use a space in the ReWriteRule after the 9 in [A-Za-z0-9-], what's the best way to handle spaces in URLs with the rewrites?

Thank You All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this rule by including space in your character class:

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([A-Za-z0-9\s-]+)/?$ /categories.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `\s` to the Regex...
That matches whitespace.

`([A-Za-z0-9\-\s]+)`